# Why is my typeahead form field not working after AJAX render?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a `vouchers#index.html.erb` in which I want a voucher to be created. I can successfully render my form however the problem I have is that my typeahead field is not working.

I have set this button to render a _form:

```
  <div class='row'>
    <%= link_to 'New Voucher', new_voucher_path, id: 'new_voucher_btn', class:'btn btn-md btn-primary', remote: true %>
  </div>
```

My Controller:

```
  def new
    @voucher = Voucher.new
    @voucher.voucherdetails.build

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @voucher }
      format.js
    end
  end
```

New.js.erb

```
$('#new_voucher_btn').hide().after('<%= j render("form") %>'); //Hide 'New Voucher' button after clicking.
$(".datepicker").datepicker({ changeMonth: true, changeYear: true, dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy" }); //add the datepicker
```

Voucher.js

```
jQuery(function() {  
  var customers = jQuery.parseJSON( gon.customer_typeahead )
  // This shows the Typeahead when typing
  $('.search_cst').typeahead({
    source: customers,
    display: 'name',
    val: 'id'
  });
  //This sets the value of customer
  $('#customer_search').on("change", '#voucher_voucherdetails_attributes_0_s002', function() {
    if (this.value != '') {
      var current =$('.search_cst').typeahead("getActive");
      if (current) {
        $('.search_cst').val(current.name);
        $('.search_cst_id').val(current.id);
      }
    } else {
      $('.search_cst').val('');
      $('.search_cst_id').val('');
    }
  });

}); //Function
```

_form.html.erb (The typeahead field included only)

```
<%= f.fields_for :voucherdetails do |vd| %>
  <div class='form-group' id='customer_search' data-provide="typeahead">
    <%= vd.label :s002, "Customer:" %>
    <%= vd.text_field :s002, class:'search_cst form-control' %>
    <%= vd.hidden_field :s002, class: 'search_cst_id' %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

A Voucher `has_many :voucherdetails`& `accepts_nested_attributes_for :voucherdetails, allow_destroy: :true`.

Voucherdetail `belongs_to :voucher`

I would like to note that the typeahead works if i render the form by visiting the url voucher/new. I believe that the problem is that I'm not initialising the typeahead properly after the AJAX call.

N.B I'm using bootstrap3-typeahead.js v 4.0.2 [Found Here](https://github.com/bassjobsen/Bootstrap-3-Typeahead)

I inherited this codebase from a previous developer (Hence the odd naming in places).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question; I placed

```
var customers = jQuery.parseJSON( gon.customer_typeahead )
// This shows the Typeahead when typing
$('.search_cst').typeahead({
  source: customers,
  display: 'name',
  val: 'id'
});
//This sets the value of s002
$('#customer_search').on("change",'#voucher_voucherdetails_attributes_0_s002', function() {
  if (this.value != '') {
    var current =$('.search_cst').typeahead("getActive");
    if (current) {
      $('.search_cst').val(current.name);
      $('.search_cst_id').val(current.id);
    }
  } else {
    $('.search_cst').val('');
    $('.search_cst_id').val('');
  }
}); //Customer_search on change
```

Into `new.js.erb` & it worked. I had tried this previously but think the difference this time being  `$('#customer_search').on("change", '#voucher...;` instead of `$(document).on("change")...;`

Which initialises the typeahead through the AJAX call.